# Microchip PIC12F1501 write/read flash

Tags: c, pic, flash-memory

For my project, using PIC12F1501, I am using NCO peripheral to pulse my circuit and I will be operating it at 2 modes of operation, namely,  Calibration mode & Normal operation mode.

The underlying circuit operates best at a particular frequency and to find out that particular frequency, I need to have a frequency sweep once in lifetime, store that frequency value in flash and every other time, it operates in normal operation where it fetches the operating frequency from the flash.

The switch between calibration and normal operation mode is done by a Digital input.

**Calibration mode:**

- Sweep the NCO frequency from 800kHz to 999kHz at a duty cycle of about 50% using PFM mode
- Find the best operating point (using AN pins)
- Store values in Flash.

**Normal operation:**

- Read the values from flash
- Initialize NCO frequency values with the read variables
- Do other functions.

As mentioned before, the calibration is done only once and the value has to be stored in a particular location in flash. Every other time, when the circuit is (re)started, the normal operation mode reads the flash and initializes the NCO accordingly.

I tried using the routines given in memory.c but the FLASH_WriteWord() requires me to declare a variable unit16_t ramBuf[16] which already takes 32 bytes and with other declarations, I am running out of space. I tried to modify this write word as below, but still I wasn't able to get it working.

**Problem:**
Could someone help me to write two 16bit data in the flash only during calibration and can be fetched while normal operation mode? My code is below...

**main.c:**

```
/* Flash Memory */
 #define NCOFreq_addr 0x0380

/* Definitions for RAM Memory Allocation */

uint16_t ramBuf[WRITE_FLASH_BLOCKSIZE]; // Needed for writing block
uint16_t PWMValue[2];


void Calibrate()
{

// Code for PWM Sweep       


      PWMValue[0] = PWMSweep; 
      PWMValue[1] = ADC_GetConversion(0);




FLASH_WriteWord(NCOFreq_addr, ramBuf, PWMValue); // Write Values to Flash
__delay_ms(1000);

Calib_DONE = 0x01; // Set this so that the calibration is done only once. 

}


void ReadData()
{
PWMValue[0] = FLASH_ReadWord(NCOFreq_addr);
__delay_ms(1000);

PWMValue[1] = FLASH_ReadWord(NCOFreq_addr+1); 
__delay_ms(1000); 



NCO1INCH = PWMValue[0] >> 8; 
NCO1INCL = PWMValue[0] & 0xFF;


Freq_read = 0x01; // Set this when the frequency is read once. 
}

/*
                     Main application
 */
 void main(void)
{
// initialize the device
SYSTEM_Initialize();


Calib_DONE = 0x00;
Freq_read = 0x00;


while (1)
{

    if ( EN_CALIB_GetValue() == 0) // Calibration mode
    { 

        if ( (Calib_DONE & 0x01) != 1) // If calibration is not done, call calibrate function.
        {
            Calibrate(); 
        } 

    }

    else // Normal operation mode
    {

        if ((Freq_read & 0x01) != 1) // If frequency is not read, call calibrate function.
        {
            ReadData();
        }


        // Other operations

        } 
     }
    // Add your application code
   }
}
```

**memory.c**

```
void FLASH_WriteWord(uint16_t flashAddr, uint16_t *ramBuf, uint16_t *word)
{
uint16_t blockStartAddr = (uint16_t)(flashAddr & ((END_FLASH-1) ^ (ERASE_FLASH_BLOCKSIZE-1)));
uint8_t offset = (uint8_t)(flashAddr & (ERASE_FLASH_BLOCKSIZE-1));
uint8_t i;

// Entire row will be erased, read and save the existing data
for (i=0; i<ERASE_FLASH_BLOCKSIZE; i++)
{
    ramBuf[i] = FLASH_ReadWord((blockStartAddr+i));
}

// Write at offset
ramBuf[offset] = word[0];
ramBuf[offset+1] = word[1];

// Writes ramBuf to current block
FLASH_WriteBlock(blockStartAddr, ramBuf);
}
```

Comment: You cannot escape the 32 bytes buffer requirement...  You can ceclare the write buffer on the stack as a local variable in FLASH_WriteWord(), you may need to disable interrupts while writing to eeprom, to avoid any stack overflow. You can also declare that buffer as a union with data that can be safely overwritten while in calibration mode.